# Quick refresh on page on SAVE

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS File**

```
buttons:
{
    save: function ()
    {
        calEvent.id = id;
        id++;
        calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
        calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
        calEvent.title = titleField.val();
        calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

        //post to events.php
        $.post("events.php",
        {
            action: "save",
            start: calEvent.start.getTime() / 1000,
            end: calEvent.end.getTime() / 1000,
            title: calEvent.title,
            body: calEvent.body,
            id: calEvent.id
        });

        $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
        $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
        $dialogContent.dialog("close");
    },
    cancel: function ()
    {
        $dialogContent.dialog("close");
    }
}
}).show();
```

**HTML File**

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Datum: </span><span class="date_holder"></span> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="start">Begin Tijd: </label><select name="start"><option value="">Select Start Time</option></select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="end">Eind Tijd: </label><select name="end"><option value="">Select End Time</option></select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="title">Afspraak reden: </label><input type="text" name="title" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="body">Extra informatie: </label><textarea name="body"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This will save arrays to the database
How to make it refresh when clicking "SAVE" button .

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple refresh function of javascript:

```
location.reload();
```

However when you don't really want to refresh the page, but only 'refresh' the content of a page. You will be happier with [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 
I suggest you to read some basic tutorials on the internet if your not familier with ajax as they will explain it far better then i would.

Comment: Where do i put `location.reload();`  in de code im a beginner.
And i readed that, i couldnt figure it out :(

Comment: Well you place it inside the code where you 'catch' your button click. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NG2Y/).

Comment: Thanks i added a succes code `success: function () {
      location.reload();
      }`  this will work form me right now. Is it for content refresh only simple as this ?

Comment: Your page will refresh, yes. When you have a function that will read content out of the database amd place it in the page, it will do that function again as it starts the page again.

Comment: You can communicate to your database with PHP. One method is a PDO connection. You can look up some tutorials how to update, import and select items from your database :) When you can't figure it out you can always ask a new question. Note that you should first show some effort :P

Answer (score 0):

Added `location.reload()`. Please check below code

```
buttons:
{
    save: function ()
    {
        calEvent.id = id;
        id++;
        calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
        calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
        calEvent.title = titleField.val();
        calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

        //post to events.php
        $.post("events.php",
        {
            action: "save",
            start: calEvent.start.getTime() / 1000,
            end: calEvent.end.getTime() / 1000,
            title: calEvent.title,
            body: calEvent.body,
            id: calEvent.id
        });

        $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
        $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
        $dialogContent.dialog("close");

        //reload page
        location.reload();
    },
    cancel: function ()
    {
        $dialogContent.dialog("close");
    }
}
}).show();
```